# $user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) Not working no errors

Tags: wp-insert-post

Below insert of new user does not work. I have no idea why not. There are no error messages send to debug.txt or to screen. I have also checked a bunch of thread about this insert. But it seems my code should be correct. But not working.

What do I do wrong in this code?

All input fields are correct filled.

```
if($loggedin == 'no'){

    $userdata = array(
'user_login'        =>  $user_email,
'user_pass'         =>  $pass,
'user_email'        =>  $user_email,
'display_name'      =>  $first_name . ' ' . $last_name,
'nickname'          =>  $first_name . ' ' . $last_name,
'first_name'        =>  $first_name,
'last_name'         =>  $last_name,     
'user_registered' =>    date('Y-m-d h:i:s'),
    );
    $user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;

if( is_wp_error( $user_id  ) ) {
echo $return->get_error_message();
}

    if($user_id && $user_id != 0){                  
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'gender', $_POST['gender']);
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'city', $_POST['city']);
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'age',  $_POST['age']);
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'bank_account', 0);
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_status', 0);

        if(!is_admin() ) {
            wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $user_id, 'role' => 'participant' ) ) ;
            $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
            $user->set_role('participants');
        }

        $info = array();
        $info['user_login'] = $user_email;
        $info['user_password'] = $pass;
        $info['remember'] = true;

        $user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );
    }

    echo 'registered';
}
```

Instead of insert I also try update. So disabled whole insert block and update that part with this below. Again no new user is added!

```
    $user_id = wp_create_user( $user_email, $pass, $user_email );

$wpdb->update( 
    $wpdb->prefix.'users', 
    array( 
        'ID'                            =>  $user_id,
        'display_name'      =>  $first_name . ' ' . $last_name,
        'nickname'              =>  $first_name . ' ' . $last_name,
        'first_name'            =>  $first_name,
        'last_name'             =>  $last_name,     
        'user_registered' =>    date('Y-m-d h:i:s'),            
    ), 
    array( 'ID' => $user_id ), 
    array( '%d', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s' ), 
    array( '%d' ) 
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where `$return` is being set. Try changing

```
if( is_wp_error( $user_id  ) ) {
    echo $return->get_error_message();
}
```

to

```
if ( is_wp_error( $user_id  ) ) {
    echo $user_id->get_error_message();
}
```

...and that should hopefully display any error messages that are generated.

Comment: no it did not display any kind of errors

Comment: Does `var_dump( $user_id );` show you anything useful?

Comment: nothing at all. Can I write directly to a file when doing the var_dump?

Comment: See code at start. Also try $wpdb->update()

Comment: What's the code to generate `$loggedin`? Are you sure it responds with `'no'` and not, say, boolean `false`?

Comment: I forgot to close if($loggedin == 'no') with if($loggedin == 'no'){ }. That causes this issue. Thanks for replying to this thread.